# Why can't I use curly braces with a `for` loop in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops, for-loop

The [Ruby Documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-do) says that "`do/end` is equivalent to curly braces", so why is it that when I attempt to do the following I do not receive any output:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
for i in a {
  puts i
}
```

When I perform the above I receive no output (but I don't receive an error message either). However, when I do the following everything is as it should be:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
for i in a do
  puts i
end
#=> 1
#=> 2 
#=> 3
```

I know this can be done more idiomatically with the `each` statement, but that's not what I'm asking. What am I not understanding here?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I get a "syntax error, unexpected end-of-input" for the first example, just like you would expect, since it is missing the `end` keyword for ending the `for`/`in` expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The [Ruby Documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-do) says that "`do/end` is equivalent to curly braces"

No, it doesn't. It says (**bold** emphasis mine):

> **In this context**, `do`/`end` is equivalent to curly braces […]

What "in this context" means is defined directly before the half-sentence you quoted:

> ## `do`
>
> Paired with `end`, can delimit **a code block**

So, "in this context" here refers to the context of a *block*.

> so why is it that when I attempt to do the following I do not receive any output

Because this is a completely different context, again quoting from the documentation you linked to:

> `do` can **also** (optionally) appear at the end of a `for`/`in` statement. (See `for` for an example.)

The "also" in that sentence makes it very clear that this is a *different* usage of the keyword `do` that has nothing to do with the usage discussed in this section. And if you look at [the documentation of `for`](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-for), you can see that there is no mention of curly braces being allowed.

> When I perform the above I receive no output (but I don't receive an error message either).

That is not true. Your code is syntactically invalid because it is missing the `end` keyword to end the `for`/`in` expression, therefore you get a "syntax error, unexpected end-of-input" on line 4:

```sh
ruby -c -e 'a = [1, 2, 3]
for i in a {
  puts i
}'
# -e:4: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
```

And if you add the missing `end`, you get a `` in `<main>': undefined method `a' for main:Object (NoMethodError) `` on line 2:

```sh
ruby -e 'a = [1, 2, 3]
for i in a {
  puts i
}
end'
# -e:2:in `<main>': undefined method `a' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Again, this is expected because curly braces delimit a code block, so

```ruby
a {
  puts i
}
```

is interpreted as a code block being passed to `a` and since variables cannot receive arguments, only methods can, `a` must be a method. Therefore, Ruby rightfully complains about not finding a method named `a`.

There are three ways of delimiting the iterator expression from the loop body expression in a `for`/`in` loop (and the same applies to `while` and `until` loops, actually):

1. An *expression separator*. An expression separator can either be

   1. a semicolon `;`
   2. a newline
2. The keyword `do`

So, the following would all be valid fixes for your code:

```ruby
# non-idiomatic
for i in a; puts i end

# non-idiomatic
for i in a
puts i end

# the same but with idiomatic indentation and whitespace
for i in a
  puts i
end

# idiomatic
for i in a do puts i end

# redundant, non-idiomatic
for i in a do
  puts i
end
```

Note, that when I say "idiomatic" above, that is to be interpreted relative, since actually `for`/`in` loops *as a whole* are completely non-idiomatic, and you would rather do this:

```
a.each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

or maybe

```
a.each(&method(:puts))
```

It is in general preferred to not mix I/O and data transformation, so another idiomatic solution would be to transform the data to the desired output first, then output it, like this:

```
puts a.join("\n")
```

Except that [`Kernel#puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) will already treat `Array` arguments special and print each element on its own line (as documented at [`IO#puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-puts)), so the *real* correct idiomatic solution for your code would be just:

```
puts a
```

Comment: Excellent explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the documentation here: [For loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-for+Loop)
It states:

> Like while and until, the do is optional. The for loop is similar to
>   using each, **but does not create a new variable scope**.

And also

> The for loop is rarely used in modern ruby programs.

So, be less Pythonic :) using [Enumerator#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) instead:

```
a.each { |a| puts a }
```

Comment: "but does not create a new variable scope" - could you explain why the implication of this is that we can't use curly braces with for loop?

Comment: seeker, ye shall find that `for i in [1,2,3] do; s = 'cat'; end; s #=> 'cat'` runs just fine. If `do; s = 'cat'; end` created a new scope for `s` (as would a block), the last line (`s`) would raise an exception.